# A specific query selector is not valid in Firefox but works in Chrome and Edge

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form generated using Kendo (working with .NET V4) that has labels with a bunch of nested divs within them.

I'm trying to dynamically hide some of the input fields/labels depending on the selection of a dropdown in the form.

I'm currently selecting the items in a function that toggles the elements to hide. The function kind of looks like this:

```js
function toggleItemDisplayForDepositChgType(e) {
    var elements = [
        { el: 'div.editor-label:has(label[for="includeInACH"])', show: false },
        { el: 'div.editor-field:has(#includeInACH)', show: false },
        //...
    ];

    var showArHoGLOverride = false;

    if (e && e.model) {
        showArHoGLOverride = e.model.chgTypeID == @((int)(EE.ChargeType.Deposit));
    } else {
        showArHoGLOverride = $('#chgTypeID').val() == @((int)(EE.ChargeType.Deposit));
    }

    $('#arGLOverride').data("kendoComboBox").enable(showArHoGLOverride);
    $('#hoCreditGLOverride').data("kendoComboBox").enable(showArHoGLOverride);

    elements.forEach(function (item) {
        var el = document.querySelector(item.el);

        if (showArHoGLOverride === item.show) {
            el.style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            el.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
}
```

The selector seems to be read correctly in Chrome, Edge, and Safari but in Firefox I get the following errror:

> Document.querySelector: 'div.editor-label:has(label[for="includeInACH"])' is not a valid selector

Comment: Firefox does not support `:has`: https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas (yet)

Comment: You have to set a flag in FF for :has to be recognised.

Comment: @somethinghere Yup, that was it. I had to update the hiding/showing of it using jQuery since `querySelector` wasn't accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended updating the query selector to use jQuery instead:

```
var el = document.querySelector(item.el);
```

to

```
var $el = $(item.el);
```

Comment: It solves the problem but is a sad resolution. JQuery really shouldn’t be the answer anymore. You could have used a selector and then closest to do the same thing. This makes me sad (glad you found a solution but still)

Comment: We use jQuery throughout the whole codebase at my job, so although I agree, the solution applies regarding the context we're using. Trust me, I hate JQuery